# How to get the caller method information from Around advise

Tags: aspectj

ThisJoinPoint can only get the current method information, anyway to get the caller method information?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the special variable `thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart` which holds the static part of the enclosing JoinPoint.

Mentioned [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-thisJoinPoint.html) (example) and [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-advice.html#reflective-access-to-the-join-point) (docs)

Or if using annotation-based AspectJ, pass following to the advice method's parameters, e.g.:

```
@Before("call( /* your pointcut definition */ )")
public void myCall(JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart)
{
     // ...
}
```

Mentioned [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html)

Comment: how to get this from @AspectJ syntax?

Comment: Pass this to the advice method's parameters: `JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart` (taken from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html))

Answer (score 0):

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before(value = "execution(public * findAll())")
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint pp){
        System.out.println("before advice called ....get calling method Signature"+pp.getSignature());
        System.out.println("before advice called ....get calling method name"+pp.getSignature().getName());
    }

}
```