# Determining which method triggered an aspect

Tags: java, aspectj

I was wondering if there is anyway of determining what method was active when this aspect was triggered. I found the method JointPoint.getSourceLocation() which returns the source code line. I realised I could try to parse that source file and try to determine the method from that... but there seems like there ought to be a better way.

Basically, if has the following code:

```
 class Monkey{
      public void feed( Banana b ){
           b.eat()
      }
 }
 class Banana{
    private static int bananaIdGen;
    public final int bananaId = ++bananaIdGen;
    private boolean eaten = false;

    public void eat(){
         if( eaten )
              throw IllegalStateException( "Already eaten." );
         else
              eaten = true;
    }
 }
```

I'd like to have an aspect like

```
 @After("call(void Banana.eat()) && target(bbb)") 
 public void whereEaten( Banana bbb ){
      ....
 }
```

Where in the body I could print out something like `"Banana 47 eaten by org.example.Monkey(org.example.Banana)".

The reason is that that I would like to throw an error if a method has been called by a method without a certain annotation on it. For that I'd need to have the Method of the method.

Comment: I've added code sample which, I suppose, solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5630809/680503) with its `thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart` can help you.

But the best way to solve your problem is to construct the right join point using `withincode` and `call` pointcuts as in example [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-development.html) (see `Contract Enforcement` section). This way you prevent calls from methods with or without certain annotation.

The list of pointcuts is available [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html).

What about your sample code lets introduce annotation:

```
package com.riapriority.test;

public @interface CanEat {
}
```

Our `Banana` class:

```
package com.riapriority.test;

public class Banana {
    private static int bananaIdGen;
    private final int bananaId = ++bananaIdGen;
    private boolean eaten = false;

    public void eat() {
        if (eaten)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already eaten.");
        else
            eaten = true;
    }

    public int getBananaId() {
        return bananaId;
    }
}
```

Our `Monkey` class with corresponding annotation:

```
package com.riapriority.test;

public class Monkey {
    @CanEat
    public void feed(Banana b) {
        b.eat();
    }
}
```

Our `Airplane` class which, of course, can't eat and so hasn't `@CanEat` annotation:

```
package com.riapriority.test;

public class Airplane {
    public void feed(Banana b) {
        b.eat();
    }
}
```

Our simple main class for testing:

```
package com.riapriority.test;

public class WithincodeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Banana monkeyBanana = new Banana();
        Monkey monkey = new Monkey();
        monkey.feed(monkeyBanana);
        try {
            monkey.feed(monkeyBanana);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        Banana airplaneBanana = new Banana();
        Airplane airplane = new Airplane();
        try {
            airplane.feed(airplaneBanana);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

So we need to avoid eating bananas by Airplane. And the corresponding aspect to obtain this:

```
package com.riapriority.test;

import java.text.MessageFormat;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class EatingAspect {
    @Pointcut("call(void Banana.eat()) && target(banana)")
    public void eatCall(Banana banana) {
    }

    @Pointcut("@withincode(CanEat)")
    public void canEat() {
    }

    @AfterReturning("eatCall(banana) && canEat()")
    public void whereEaten(Banana banana,
                           JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart thisEnclosingStaticPart) {
        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Banana {0} eaten by {1}", banana.getBananaId(),
                thisEnclosingStaticPart.getSignature()));
    }

    @Before("eatCall(banana) && !canEat()")
    public void forbidEating(Banana banana,
                             JoinPoint.EnclosingStaticPart thisEnclosingStaticPart) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(MessageFormat.format("Can''t eat {0} by {1}", banana.getBananaId(),
                thisEnclosingStaticPart.getSignature()));
    }
}
```

So now our test main class produces the right output:

```
Banana 1 eaten by void com.riapriority.test.Monkey.feed(Banana)
Already eaten.
Can't eat 2 by void com.riapriority.test.Airplane.feed(Banana)
```

Hope this solves your problem.