# Getting the name of class intersected by a pointcut

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

```
class SampleClass{
   ChildClass childClass;
   public void init(){
       childClass = ChildUtil.getChildClass();
       childClass.callService("batman");
   }
}
```

**Aspect**

```
 @Aspect
    public class CallServiceAspect{
        @After("execution(* com.xyz.ChildClass.callService(..))")
        public void afterCallService(JoinPoint jp){
           log.debug(jp.getTarget().getName());
         }
    }
```

I want the name of class within which the callService method was intersected by the aspect(i.e. SampleClass). Is there any way to obtain it?

Comment: `callService` is static?

Comment: ^nope. Let me edit it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the caller method information from Around advise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630809/how-to-get-the-caller-method-information-from-around-advise)

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov Didn't get much from that.

Comment: I don't think it's possible what you want with Spring AOP. The information you want to get out of Spring AOP is somewhat dynamic: you can call `childClass.callService()` from class `SampleClass` or from `BatmanClass` and I don't think Spring would know which came from where. I think you need to look at a pure AspectJ solution.

Comment: If you would use plain AspectJ you could BUT you would have to use a `call` pointcut instead of an `execution` pointcut. That way you could do `jp.getThis()` which would return the caller, however with an `execution` pointcut `this` and `target` are always the same. Else you would have to navigate the callstack and determine the caller yourself.

Comment: ^Hmmm...yeah! With call I can do that. But now I'll need to know difference between call and execution. That was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you still need an answer, I can provide you with an AspectJ example and also explain the basic difference between `call` and `execution` pointcuts. Just let me know or otherwise answer your own question and close it by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of intercepting through `execution`, I used `call`. Then I was able to use `jp.getThis()` to get SampleClass name.